# How do i use grep command with multiple search string?

Tags: unix, terminal, grep

When i use : `ps -o user,cmd`  My output is :

```
User    CMD
0        in.telnetd
0        sh
0        processd
0        processe
0        in.telnetd
0        -sh
0        top
```

I want to get 2 row (which contains processd & processe) after i do grep command .

What i used :

```
 1.   ps -o user,cmd | grep "processd\|processe"
 2.   ps -o user,cmd | grep processd | grep processe
```

Am i using correct format to grep what i want or is it like i need to modify my query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[SOLVED]`

After some trial and error i just got to know about `-E` option .

`ps -o user,cmd | grep -E processd\|processe`

Comment: For your information: there are three `grep`-like commands: the regular `grep` (which uses normal regular expressions), `fgrep` or `grep -F` (which uses fix strings) and `egrep` or `grep -E` (extended grep, which makes it possible to combine different regular expressions).

Answer (score 1):

one way would be:

```
ps -o user,cmd | grep "process[de]"
```

of course you might end up catching also lines like

```
0        /some/other/app --with --lots of arguments including also processe
```

to make sure you do not catch that, you should probably use awk.

Answer (score 1):

You were looking for

```
ps -o user,cmd | egrep "processd|processe"
```

When I need to check logfiles, I use something similar:

```
interesting="keyword1"
interesting+="|key2
interesting+="|key3"
skip="garbage1"
skip+="|garb2"
skip+="|garb3"

grep "^20150909" logfile | egrep "${interesting}" | egrep -v "${skip}"
```

Comment: Have a vote. Just FYI, I think those modern, POSIX-y folk are getting rid of `egrep` and suggesting we use `grep -E` instead.